# Spring-boot, one-to-many relationship in the same object (parent & childrens)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, rest, jpa, entity-relationship

In my spring-boot project, i want to create object "Menu" with parent and childrens values:
- Menu can have **One parent** element
- Menu can have **One or Many** childrens elements
Entity Menu.java

```
@Entity
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Menu implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Menu> childrens;

    @ManyToOne
    private Menu parent;

}
```

MenuDAO.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MenuDAO extends JpaRepository<Menu, Long> {

}
```

DemoApplication.java to add data for Test with CommandLine Runner :

- **Menu1** (parent)
- Sub-Menu1(children Of **Menu1**)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

   @Autowired
   MenuDAO menuDAO;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       Menu m1 = menuDAO.save(new Menu(null,"Menu1",null,null));
       Menu m2 = menuDAO.save(new Menu(null,"Sub-Menu1",null,m1));

   }
}
```

But whene i fetch the parent element with rest service call i get this result http://localhost:9090/menus/1:

```
{
 "name" : "Menu1",
 "_links" : {
   "self" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1"
   },
   "menu" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1"
   },
   "childrens" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1/childrens"
   },
   "parent" : {
     "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1/parent"
   }
 }
}
```

But my requirement is to fetch the data in the below JSON format:

```
{
"name" : "Menu1",
"childrens" : [{
                 "name" : "Menu2"
              }], 
"parent" : NULL,
"_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1"
  },
  "menu" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1"
  },
  "childrens" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1/childrens"
  },
  "parent" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:9090/menus/1/parent"
  }
}
}
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: StackOverflow is supposed to be in English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i have the answer after reading documentation of **Spring Data REST Reference Guide** 
Spring Data REST presents a default view of the domain model you export. but if we may need to alter the view of that model for various reasons we can use **projections and excerpts** to serve up simplified and reduced views of resources.
In My case, the first step is to create a **Prejection** Interface of my Entity **Menu** and choose all attributs i want to find in the JSON response.

```
@Projection(name = "MenuProjection", types = Menu.class)
public interface MenuProjection {
    Long getId();

    String getName();

    Menu getParent();

    List<Menu> getChildrens();

}
```

The second step is to add the property **excerptProjection** of **RepositroyRestRessource** annotation with **Menu.Class** value in my **MenuRepository** interface.
`@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = MenuProjection.class)`

JSON Response Before

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "menus" : [ {
      "name" : "cat_test1",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1"
        },
        "menu" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1"
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/parent"
        },
        "pages" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/pages"
        },
        "children" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/children"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "cat_test2",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2"
        },
        "menu" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2"
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/parent"
        },
        "pages" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/pages"
        },
        "children" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/children"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/profile/menus"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

JSON with Projection

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "menus" : [ {
      "name" : "cat_test1",
      "parent" : null,
      "id" : 1,
      "childrens" : [ {
        "name" : "cat_test2"
      } ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1"
        },
        "menu" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "childrens" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/childrens{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/parent{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "pages" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/1/pages"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "cat_test2",
      "parent" : {
        "name" : "cat_test1",
      },
      "id" : 2,
      "childrens" : [ ],
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2"
        },
        "menu" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "childrens" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/childrens{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/parent{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "pages" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/2/pages"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus{?page,size,sort,projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/profile/menus"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:9292/menus/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

So, with Spring Data Projection we can includes the data fields inside the entity resource.